# Retrieving date field from service data in angularJS

Tags: angularjs

I am accessing a service method and it is returning an array. from this I need to display a date value.

this below works fine, but any other efficient way to pick this date value ?

```
var data = myService.getData();
if (angular.isDefined(data)) {
var d = new Date(data.items[0].item[0].table.rows[0].mark[1].args[0].timeValue.seconds * 1000);
                if(!isNaN(d))
                    return (d.toDateString());
            }
```

Comment: Can you share the structure of your array?

Answer (score 1):

What's inefficient about it? It seems like the structure of the data is a bunch of nested arrays. You are accessing these values by their index O(1).

Do you want cleaner code? If so, you will need to either:

1.) Restructure your data.

2.) Move this code into a getDate() service method that returns the date value or object. (This is more of a 'push the mess under the rug' approach.)